# Google app engine python 2.7 tutorial won't run

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm following the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

my app.yaml is:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: helloworld.application
```

and helloworld.py is:

```
import webapp2


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hi')


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

The log output is:

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=10090 --admin_port=8001
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 182, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 178, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 695, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 688, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 525, in start
    options.yaml_files)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 556, in __init__
    server_configuration = ServerConfiguration(yaml_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 82, in __init__
    self._yaml_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 272, in _parse_configuration
    return appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 63, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py", line 1715, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 226, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError
```

I'm running on a macbook pro, using python 2.7
I'm using the app engine launcher. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your exception cut off? I think there should be an error message following the `EventError` exception name on the last line.

Comment: No it's not cut off, thats all it says

Comment: After saving app.yaml with text wrangler I managed to get a more informative error. `google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap 
    auth_fail_action=redirect 
    static_dir=None 
    secure=default 
    http_headers=None 
    url=/.* 
    static_files=None 
    expiration=None 
    upload=None 
    api_endpoint=None 
    script=None 
    application_readable=None 
    position=None 
    login=optional 
    mime_type=None 
    require_matching_file=None
    >
  in "/Users/Evan/helloworld/app.yaml", line 9, column 1
`

Comment: Your code looks OK to me.  For what it's worth, I was able to reproduce the above error by removing the spaces from the start  of the 'script:' line.  Maybe double check that line.  Perhaps delete and re-enter it in case it contains hidden characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I experienced the same problem too. It has something to do with the file encoding when you copy directly from the site. Avoid doing this and ensure that your file has proper yaml encoding. Here's an example to get you started for the app.yaml file

```
application: your-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.application
```

Comment: Yes this was the problem. Eventually I figured it out, but it was an unfortunate waste of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

In my case the problem was the indentation level of the "script" line.

It was like:

```
handlers:
 - url: /.*
 script: helloworld.php
```

but should be like this:

```
handlers:
 - url: /.*
   script: helloworld.php
```

Answer (score 4):

I cut-and-pasted app.yaml from Chrome into gnome-terminal, and got the same error.  Eventually I opened app.yaml in vi, and found that it contained a UTF text-direction marker.  As soon as I removed that, everything started working.

Moral of the story: if you see this error, check your app.yaml for bad markup, bad characters, and anything else bad.  (Not DOS newlines though -- the dev appserver copes with those.)

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the special character before the  application line in app.yaml. It seems not to be there but just navigate your cursor to the position before a then press backspace to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

To complete on @Fernando Basso's answer, the correct intent on the script line should be two spaces, but not a tab as it would be read as a \t character which would also generate an error.